# Updating AWS credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, credentials, amazon-ses

I need advice on how I can update AWS credentials after they expire.

I'm creating a bean of AmazonSimpleEmailService this way:

```
@Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService getSesClient() {
        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder("ses-role-us-west-2", "mail-sender")
                        .build()
                        .getCredentials())
                )
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
    }
```

But when I'm trying to use it I'm getting an error:

`The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: ExpiredToken`

If I create an instance of the SES client right before each mail sending - it works correctly, but it looks like a bad practice to create a new instance before each use.

I understand that the issue with the credentials that I'm getting via STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider - they just have an expiration time.

I am wondering if there should be a way to automatically update the credentials when they are going to expire, so I'd really appreciate any advice on how to do it.

Comment: Your AWS SDK for Java V1 code is on path to deprecation. AWS recommends you update to V2. Details here -- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-end-of-support-for-aws-sdk-for-java-v1-x-on-december-31-2025/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider` will auto-refresh the credentials, but you are blocking that functionality by getting a single set of credentials and passing them into a `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` instance.

This should allow you to use the auto-refresh of the STS Provider:

```java
@Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService getSesClient() {
        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder("ses-role-us-west-2", "mail-sender")
                        .build()
                )
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try!

I also found a solution with STS client - looks like it also should work:

`@Bean
     public AmazonSimpleEmailService getSesClient(AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient) {
         return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                 .withCredentials(new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder("ses-role-us-west-2", "mail-sender")
                         .withStsClient(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.defaultClient())
                         .build())
                 .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
     }`